# How to change font size for ListView Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows Universal app and currently working on the Windows Phone part of it.  I have a ListView control on one of the pages and I've added a few items to it programmatically.  However I can't workout how to increase the fontsize of the items in the ListView.  I've tried changing the font-size but it makes no difference, the size of the text in the ListView is tiny.  Here is the current XAML.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="434" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" FontSize="24"/>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I suspect there's some template or something I need to use or that is overwriting the font-size in the XAML but I'm struggling to find any documentation about what it might be.  It's a fairly simple thing I want to do.

Comment: Have your listviewitems set the font size explicitly?

Comment: I'm adding the values to the listview via C# code and not via XAML so I have not specified fontsizes anywhere other than in the code sample above.  So I think the answer is no, but I don't know how to set that.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically your code should work but if you don't see what you want I can suspect that you could have some inner component that is overriding your font size property. In this way you don't see any error but never get what you expect.
Look at inner components, e.g. `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` with `TextBlock`

If it desn't solve your problem check into App.xaml something that  is overriding this property similar to this

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" /> 
</Style>
```

to make it work I suggest to you to add `TextElement.FontSize="24"` property to your listview

Comment: When I try your XAML and add ListView.ItemTemplate it says an attribute name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem with the items in my listView. You can do this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="434" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" FontSize="24">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Your List View Item"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It will be nice to give a brief explanation rather than posting only the code. Most of the time its hard to ponder the entire code to see what change you have made it to get it work.

Comment: Actually am still new to programming Windows App but my explanation would be that the listView FontSize did not change because the ItemTemplate was not defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your xaml code and it should work:

```
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my XAML code to set the font size and text color of ListView Items.

```
    <ListView x:Name="daysInfoListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="113" Margin="10,193,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Foreground="#FF0000CC" Background="#FFCC0000" FontSize="12" IsTabStop="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0000CC"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```